# Problems with Hand Wave Gesture C# Script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, gesture

I had this code working last night to register hand waving in Unity. Unfortunately I began working on Facial Recognition today and the major change I made to this code was creating a new script to handle the BodySourceManagement. This is when the handwaving stopped being registered in the Debug Log for Unity. So I changed the bodymanagement to be handle within the script. So I have three different scripts essentially tracking the body. A hand movement script, this handwaving script, and the facial recognition.

Note, that I am a designer and I am doing this for an assignment for my class and I had to teach my self all the code using various sites. I've been doing this as a hobby for two years.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using Microsoft.Kinect;
using Windows.Kinect;
//using System;

public class HandWaveGesture : MonoBehaviour {
    //public MyBodySourceManager bodysource;
    private KinectSensor Sensor;
    private BodyFrameReader Reader;
    public Body[] bodies;
    private int bodyCount;
    public bool waveSegment1;
    public bool waveComplete;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        Sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

        if (Sensor != null)
        {
            Reader = Sensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();

            if (!Sensor.IsOpen)
            {
                Sensor.Open();
            }
        } 

    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (Reader != null)
        {
            Reader.Dispose();
            Reader = null;
        }

        if (Sensor != null)
        {
            if (Sensor.IsOpen)
            {
                Sensor.Close();
            }

            Sensor = null;
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Reader != null)
        {
            var frame = Reader.AcquireLatestFrame();
            if (frame != null)
            {
                if (bodies == null)
                {
                    bodies = new Body[Sensor.BodyFrameSource.BodyCount];
                }

                frame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(bodies);

                frame.Dispose();
                frame = null;
            }
        }    

            WaveSegments ();
    }

    void WaveSegments()

    {
        if (Reader != null) 
            {
            var frame = Reader.AcquireLatestFrame ();

            if (frame != null)
                {
                if (bodies == null) {
                    bodies = new Body[Sensor.BodyFrameSource.BodyCount];
                }

                frame.GetAndRefreshBodyData (bodies);

                frame.Dispose ();
                frame = null;

                int idx = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < Sensor.BodyFrameSource.BodyCount; i++) {
                    if (bodies [i].IsTracked) 
                    {
                        idx = i;
                    }
                }
                if (idx > -1) 
                    {
                        // Hand above elbow
                            if (bodies [idx].Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y > 
                                bodies [idx].Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.Y)
                            {
                                // Hand right of elbow
                                if (bodies [idx].Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.X > 
                                    bodies [idx].Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.X)
                                    {
                                        Debug.Log ("Part1Wave Occured");
                                        waveSegment1=true;
                                        waveComplete=false;
                                    }
                                else
                                    {
                                        waveSegment1=false;
                                    }
                            }
                            if(bodies [idx].Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y > 
                               bodies [idx].Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.Y && waveSegment1)
                            {
                                if (bodies [idx].Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.X > 
                                    bodies [idx].Joints[JointType.ElbowRight].Position.X)
                                    {
                                        waveSegment1=false;
                                        Debug.Log ("You have Completed a Wave");
                                        waveComplete=true;
                                    }
                                else
                                    {

                                    }
                            }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a quick note, please don't use the "unity" tag for "unity3d" questions, it is intended for questions about the Microsoft dependency injection API. (Also, code formatting is best done with indents, not 'pre' or 'code' tags.)

Comment: As for the code, it would be a big help to know which parts *are* working. if you add more Debug.Log statements you will see where it is getting to. Also considering running in the debugger (MonoDevelop or Visual Studio) with breakpoints, so you can step through the code line by line.

Comment: Ahh, you're right! Thank you for that advice. And I will definitely add more statements and see what comes up! I was just so frustrated when Unity wasn't giving me an error either. Thanks again.

Comment: Looking at the code, it looks like `waveComplete` would toggle on every frame as long as your right hand is above and to the right of your right elbow - you may want to revisit the logic. Alternately, if your goal is only to detect a wave, you may want to use the Visual Gesture Builder that comes along with the Kinect v2 SDK.